# Python - Contar valores com separação

Tags: python-3.x

Estou precisando criar um `barplot` com a contagem de itens dentro de uma coluna:

```py
0       DevFullStack,CientistadeDados,blockChain,DEVOPS
1                                                  Java
2                                             Java;.Net
3                     Salesforce;SAP;ArquiteturadeDados
4                     Python;Java;React;NodeJS;Angular6
5                                  Java;BigData;Alteryx
6     Mobile;DevOps;ArquitetoCloud;CientistaIA;Desen...
7                                      Java;Python;.NET
8                                    React;Node;Angular
9                       Python;Arquitetodesoluções;.Net
10                                              BigData
11                                      Java;.NET;COBOL
12                              Java;RPA;Python;Angular
13                                         Powerbuilder
14    Ograudedificuldadeparacontrataçãodeprofissiona...
15                                                  SAP
16                                           SpringBoot
17                                                 Java
18                        Azure;Java;Full-Stack;Xamarim
19                            Tibco;Altair;C;Sharepoint
20                                          DataScience
21                                                  NaN
22    Java;Angular;React;TecnologiasDevOps;NodeJS;Py...
23                       Java;C++;Python;Angular;NodeJS
24                  Java;Python;Angular;React;.Net;Java
25                                                  NaN
26            Java;Python;NoSQL;BigData;AWS;Oracle;.Net
```

Notem que há diversas respostas e cada linha está separada por `;`.

Comment: split(';')  nao faz o que queres?